# how to create a paypal sandbox account

Tags: paypal

I am trying to create a PayPal sandbox account but not having any luck.

I'm following the instructions on creating sandbox test accounts
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

I go to Dashboard \ sandbox \ accounts as it says to do
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

Then it says to click the "Create Account button". But I don't see one.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. You have to have a PayPal account before you can create a sandbox account.